# Is it possible to overlay local LDAP attributes on top of a replicated tree?

Tags: ldap, authentication, login, sssd

A central LDAP server provides user data as `posixAccount`, whereby the attributes `homeDirectory` and `loginShell` are empty.  I want allow users in this central LDAP server to access a Linux system.

If I use `syncrepl` to replicate the data to a local LDAP server, I can use `sssd` to set the `homeDirectory`.  I could also use `sssd` to set everyone's  `loginShell` to, say, `/usr/bin/bash`.

However, I would like to be able to set `loginShell` on a per-user basis, mainly to allow setting the shell to `/sbin/nologin` in order to lock individual users out of the system.

Is it possible to combine replicated data with local data in this way? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at overlay [slapo-translucent](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-translucent).

Comment: That looks like the answer to my question, thanks. However, could I also just exclude ```loginShell``` and ```homeDirectory``` from the attributes to be synced?